# Why Android Studio doesn't recognize this dependency library?

Tags: android, gradle

I have been using gradle library dependencies for a while.

Some of them are *deprecated*, but even though they are no longer maintened, they still very useful.

I'm trying to implement this [MenuDrawer library](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) but Android Studio fails to import the classes.

[image]

On the other hand, it succeeds to import the gradle dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:3.0.4'
}
```

[CHANGELOG](http://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to sync project with Gradle provided dependencies. This usually is asked for once you edit Gradle file, but you may start it by hand via menu `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files`. Then you can <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while having cursor on `MenuDrawer` text to see if there's option to import something related.

BTW: [3.0.6 is most recent version](http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/simonvt/menudrawer/menudrawer/), so check it first to see if that solves the issue.

Finally, you should consider using Support Library's implementation perhaps instead: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: There was nothing wrong about syncing the project: as I said before: *"it succeeds to import the gradle dependency"*. However, the real problem was the `3.0.6 version`, which is not included in the changelog. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure I get the 3.0.6 remark? I checked version directly on jcenter (see link in edited answer). Or you mean using 3.0.6 solves your problem?

Comment: Using older versions of the library was the real problem. https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Oh, seems it's really deprecated :) Glad update helped. Another reason to switch to Google's support lib for navigation drawer